# Udp Server on ActiveX Form

Tags: delphi, activex, indy

When I use TIdUDPServer on **ActiveXForm**, OnUDPRead event of the Udp Server does not trigger.
If I check IdUDPServer.Active status, it's "true". But why OnUDPRead never triggered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TIdUDPServer` is a multi-threaded component.  Each item in its `Bindings` collection listens for data in its own worker thread.

The `TIdUDPServer.ThreadedEvent` property is false by default, which means each `Binding` triggers the `OnUDPRead` event in the context of the main UI thread by calling `TThread.Synchronize()`, which does not work inside of a DLL unless both DLL and EXE are compiled with Runtime Packages enabled so they share a common copy of the RTL.  Otherwise, the DLL will have its own separate copy of the RTL than the main EXE's RTL (assuming the EXE is using the VCL at all).  Without Runtime Packages enabled, the main EXE would have to explicitly call into the DLL periodically to pump the DLL's message queue for `Synchronize()` requests, since they will not appear in the EXE's message queue (assuming the EXE would even know how to process them if they did).

If you set `ThreadedEvent` to true, `Synchronize()` will not be used, thus the `OnUDPRead` event will be triggered in the context of each `Binding` thread.  You would just have to make sure that your `OnUDPRead` handler code is written to be thread-safe.

Comment: thanks for your help. 
Related [question] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935870/delphi-thread-not-executing-in-activex-form-but-does-elsewhere). maybe it helps someone...